# $(this).position.left returns empty

Tags: jquery, this

Can someone explain and help me why the `$(this).position.left` is empty?

```
$('#wrapper img, #beschrijving').click(function (obj) {
    var posLeft = $(this).position.left;
    $('#wrapper').animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + posLeft + 'px'
    }, 500);
});
```

The rest of the script works, because if I fill in `posLeft` with a number, it does what it supposed to do. I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) is a function, the function will return an object which contains the `left` property

```
$(this).position().left;
```

like

```
$('#wrapper img, #beschrijving').click(function (obj) {
    var posLeft = $(this).position().left;
    $('#wrapper').animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + posLeft + 'px'
    }, 500);
});
```